# Obtener el promedio de registros de una agrupación SQL

Tags: sql-server

**El objetivo:**

Obtener el  numero de  reuniones  realizadas ,  promedio del  numero de participantes en  cada Reunión, el numero  máximo  de participantes en una Reunión por día

La tabla guarda un  registro por cada usuario entrar a una video conferencia cada usuario tiene un  correo (**Email**) y cada junta tiene una clave (**ReunionCode**)  de identificación.

Les muestro un demo como  reproducir los valores de entrada  y  el resultado  que se  espera.

Como mejorar la consulta sea mas eficiente o comprensible

```
DECLARE @Participantes AS TABLE 
(ParticipanteID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Fecha date,
 ReunionCode varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 Email varchar(50) NOT NULL
 )
 
 INSERT INTO @Participantes VALUES ('2021/01/01','AAA','Email1@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/01','AAA','Email2@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/01','AAA','Email3@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/01','BBB','Email1@hotmail.com'),

                                   ('2021/01/02','CCC','Email1@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/02','DDD','Email2@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/02','EEE','Email3@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/02','EEE','Email1@hotmail.com'),

                                   ('2021/01/03','FFF','Email1@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/03','FFF','Email2@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/03','FFF','Email3@hotmail.com'),
                                   ('2021/01/03','GGG','Email4@hotmail.com')

/*
Obtener el  numero de  reuniones  realizadas ,  promedio del  numero de participantes en  cada reunion, el numero  maximo  de participantes en una reunion por dia
Resultado.

Fecha | Numero reuniones |  promedio de participantes |  maximo  de participantes 
01/01 |         2        |          2                 |         3
01/02 |         3        |          1                 |         2
01/03 |         2        |          2                 |         3

*/



SELECT 
CAST(p.Fecha as date) as fecha,
(Select Count(distinct pt.ReunionCode) as Participante
    from  @Participantes pt
    where pt.Fecha = p.Fecha) as NumeroReuniones,
(
select sum(y.Participante)/COUNT(*) from 
(
    Select pt.ReunionCode, Count(*) as Participante
    from  @Participantes pt
    where pt.Fecha = p.Fecha
    group by pt.ReunionCode
) y ) as PromedioParticipante,
(Select top 1 COUNT(*)  as Participante
    from  @Participantes pt
    where pt.Fecha = p.Fecha
    group by pt.ReunionCode
    order by Participante desc) as maximoParticipante
FROM @Participantes p
Group BY DAY(p.Fecha ), MONTH(p.Fecha ),CAST(p.Fecha  AS date),DATENAME(MONTH,p.Fecha )
ORDER BY MONTH(p.Fecha ) ASC
```

Comment: No entiendo pq en el resultado esperado te debe dar que el 01/01 hubo una reunion y el resto de los dias hubo dos reuniones, pq?

Comment: Tienes razón conteste mal el ejemplo, cambie el  resultado

Comment: sigo sin entender

Comment: Una Reunión  tiene un clave, el día 1 de enero  hay 3 registros y para saber cuantas  reuniones  pasaron en un  día es el numero de registros con  diferente  numero de clave, entonces existe la reunion 'AAA' y 'BBB' entonces el resultado son 2

Comment: el dia 1 no hay 3 registros hay 4; 3 para AAA y 1 para BBB

Comment: Tienes razon , también vi que no se mostraba que se crea la tabla Participantes

Comment: @japv respondí con el código que necesito , sabes una mejor y corta para realizar la misma consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás complicando mucho las cosas. Solo tienes que obtener el número de participantes por reunión y luego usar las funciones de agregado sobre eso. Uso un CTE, pero se puede usar también una subconsulta directamente en el `FROM`.

```
WITH cteParticipantesReunion AS(
    SELECT Fecha,
        ReunionCode,
        COUNT( Email) AS Participantes
    FROM @Participantes
    GROUP BY Fecha,
             ReunionCode
)
SELECT Fecha,
    COUNT( *)           AS NumeroReuniones,
    AVG( Participantes) AS PromedioParticipantes,
    MAX( Participantes) AS MaximoParticipantes
FROM cteParticipantesReunion
GROUP BY Fecha;
```

Comment: Excelente solución, no me gustaba la solución que hice. voy a investigar los CTE

Answer (score -1):

Tuve que hacer subconsultas para calcular cada columna , me gustaría saber si hay una forma mejor para resolver este problema

```
SELECT 
CAST(p.Fecha as date) as fecha,
(Select Count(distinct pt.Email) as Participante
    from  @Participantes pt
    where pt.Fecha = p.Fecha) as NumeroReuniones,
(
select sum(y.Participante)/COUNT(*) from 
(
    Select pt.ReunionCode, Count(*) as Participante
    from  @Participantes pt
    where pt.Fecha = p.Fecha
    group by pt.ReunionCode
) y ) as PromedioParticipante,
(Select top 1 COUNT(*)  as Participante
    from  @Participantes pt
    where pt.Fecha = p.Fecha
    group by pt.ReunionCode
    order by Participante desc) as maximoParticipante
FROM @Participantes p
Group BY DAY(p.Fecha ), MONTH(p.Fecha ),CAST(p.Fecha  AS date),DATENAME(MONTH,p.Fecha )
ORDER BY MONTH(p.Fecha ) ASC
```

Comment: Cualquier consulta que hagas sera compleja, lo otro que quiza pudieras intentar es hacer inner joins recursivos por determinado campo de modo que juntes todas las consultas, pero en sentido general tu consulta la veo bien

Comment: Tu codigo parece estar bien, pero ya esto: FROM @Participantes p
Group BY DAY(p.Fecha ), MONTH(p.Fecha ),CAST(p.Fecha  AS date),DATENAME(MONTH,p.Fecha )
ORDER BY MONTH(p.Fecha ) ASC sobra, en realidad en el from puedes poner lo que quieras que eso no va a afectar las subconsultas del select

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).